# What are the R equivalents of the Stata functions qofd(), mofd() and wofd()?

Tags: r, stata

What are the **R** equivalents of the Stata functions `qofd()`, `mofd()` and `wofd()`?

I am not looking for any **R** function that converts dates to strings (for instance, converting `10/13/2016` to `2006q4` using `qofd()`).

I want functions that convert a date into a float format which can be used directly (without conversion to other formats) in regression, and can show for example as `2006q4` when we look at the data.

Comment: Stata's weeks are defined as week 1 always starting on 1 January through to week 52 always ending on 31 December and being 8 or 9 days long. If you want an exact equivalent in R, my guess is that you will need to write your own code. Most definitions of weeks that I have seen are in terms of particular days of the week that are the first or last day of each week, thus allowing weeks to span calendar years.

Answer (score 2):

### Date

If `d` is of `Date` class then `as.numeric(d)` gives the number of days since the UNIX Epoch (which is January 1, 1970).  If a `Date` class variable is used in a regression that is the numeric vector used as shown in this example.

```
y <- (1:10)^2
x <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + 0:9
xx <- as.numeric(x)
identical(unname(coef(lm(y ~ x))), unname(coef(lm(y ~ xx))))
## [1] TRUE
```

### yearmon and yearqtr

The zoo package has `yearmon` and `yearqtr` classes that display as shown below  but are represented internally as year + fraction.  For `yearmon` the fraction is 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  For `yearqtr` the fraction is 0 for Q1, 1/4 for Q2, 2/4 for Q3 and 3/4 for Q4.

Here is how objects of these classes are rendered by default.  `format` can be used to get other formats.   See `?yearmon` in the zoo package.

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon("2000-01")
## [1] "Jan 2000"

as.yearqtr("2000-1")
## [1] "2000 Q1"
```

Here we show that regressing on a `yearmon` variable is the same as regressing on its numeric representation.  A similar example could be given for `yearqtr`.  `y` is from above.

```
ym <- as.yearmon(2000) + 0:9/12
num <- as.numeric(ym)
identical(unname(coef(lm(y ~ ym))), unname(coef(lm(y ~ num))))
## [1] TRUE
```

### weeks

The single line `nextfri` function defined in this zoo vignette:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf

cam be used to standardize dates to Fridays only.  Replace 5 in that formula with another number between 0 and 6 to get that day of the week.

```
library(zoo)

yy <- (1:365)^2
ww <- nextfri(as.Date("2019-01-01") + 0:364)

# regress yy on next Friday
lm(yy ~ ww)
```